# Stanford NLP: Chinese Part of Speech labels?

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger, part-of-speech

I am trying to find a table explaining each label in the Chinese part-of-speech tagger for the 2015.1.30 version.  I couldn't find anything on this topic.  The closest thing I could find was in the "Morphological features help POS tagging of unknown words across language varieties" article, but it doesn't explain what VC represent.  I would love to get an updated list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the tag set of the (Penn/LDC/Brandeis/UC Boulder) Chinese Treebank.

See here for details on the tag set: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~chinese/

This was documented in the parser FAQ, but I'll add it to the tagger FAQ.

Comment: The url is down.

Comment: Here is the new url: https://verbs.colorado.edu/chinese/ctb.html